# Loki - no VPN connections in network-manager tray applet

Tags: networking, wingpanel, vpn

In network-manager i can only select wireless and wired networks as well as hidden but not VPN. To connect to VPN I have to go to system settings and connect from there.

How do I add VPN menu option in network-manager?
On another note does anyone know how to add support for L2TP VPN?

Comment: You should remove the L2TP part from this question - it is best posted as a separate question.

Answer (score 2):

Its on the wishlist:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/wingpanel-indicator-network/+bug/1489486

Seems like its not coming anytime soon tho :((